# Error while using device.takeSnapshot() in androidviewclient

Tags: python-2.7, androidviewclient

I am currently using the following versions
**Python** - 2.7.10 ( 32 bit , win)
**AndroidViewClient** - androidviewclient-10.7.1-py2.7.egg

I have a simple program as below

```
import sys
import os
try:
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
pass
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
vc = ViewClient(device=device, serialno=serialno)
device.takeSnapshot().save('Menu.png','PNG')
```

This is giving me the following error

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dump.py", line 14, in <module>
    device.takeSnapshot().save('Menu.png','PNG')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-10.7.1-py2.7.egg\com\dtmilano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 678, in takeSnapshot
    image = Image.open(stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2126, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x023462A8>*
```

The Same snippet code - works for some devices and for some it doesnt 
How can i figure out what is wrong with the devices where it doesnt work 
Also please help me idetify any configuration issues as i am new to this

Comment: Can you give me a hint about what are the devices whether it works or fail? Try to find a pattern: android versions, manufacturer, etc.

Comment: Bascially , UI Automator of the Android SDK is able to capture snapshots , however device.takeSnapshot() is failing.

Comment: Does `dump -Df screenshot.png` get the screenshot?

Comment: You can also try setting `USE_ADB_FRAMEBUFFER_METHOD = True` in `adbclient.py` (around line 631) and check if the result changes.